# Three JS Gimbal Lock in rotation

Tags: javascript, rotation, three.js, quaternions, euler-angles

It seem that the quaternion rotation in Three JS is not free from Gimbal Lock.

Steps to reproduce:

1) Open [Three JS Editor](http://threejs.org/editor/).
2) Add a Cylinder and set value of z to 1.57 (the center text box in rotation).
3) Now try to change values in y or x radians ( left or right text boxes in rotation).

You would see that both x and y are performing same rotation. Any ideas how to avoid that?

AFAIK Three JS uses quaternions by default and gimbal lock only happens when you are using eular angles.

Thanks!

Comment: Euler angles are not unique. Different Euler triples can result in the same orientation. The library is working correctly.

Comment: @WestLangley, so is there any way around it? Can this be handled changing the order from "XYZ" to something else on the fly?

Comment: Is this how this editor gadget should work anyway? These look like euler angles that you explicitly set. I have no idea how to work in this editor, but if you jump into code, if you understand quaternions they should make sense. Three now relies heavily on quaternions.

Comment: What is your problem? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

In the code: try to modify the quaternion property of an object in three js instead of the rotation property. Like that you can be sure to avoid the gimbal lock by using quaternions.

In the editor you can only edit with euler angles, and since many euler angle representations may result in the same quaternion, the rotation is ambiguous;

Answer (score -1):

Regular rotation (mesh.rotation.set) uses Euler angle if you observe the mesh object.
This will rotate the mesh around Y axis by 90 degree using quaternion.

```
mesh.rotation.setFromQuaternion(some_quaternion, "XYZ", true);
var some_quaternion = new THREE.Quaternion();
some_quaternion.setFromAxisAngle(new THREE.Vector(0,1,0), Math.PI/2);
```